# My project compiles in vs2008 without a single issue but does not in 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, multibyte

I have a C++ project that will compile just fine in 2008 and in 2010 it just won't compile.

In 2010 if I change it the character set to multibyte it will compile but no strings work properly can exactly describe what happens to it, if I don't change it the below code errors and warns show up.

In 2008 it compiles and works just fine without a single issue.

I am not very bright in C++ so if possible a easy to understand response as detailed as possible would help me very much to understand what is going on and possible fix it.

Here are the errors and warns when it is not in multibyte:

```
    12  IntelliSense: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
    13  IntelliSense: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
Error   10  error C2664: 'URLDownloadToFileW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [255]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   2   error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR [256]' to 'const char *'
Error   3   error C2664: 'SetConsoleTitleW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   4   error C2664: 'GetModuleHandleW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   5   error C2664: 'GetModuleHandleW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   11  error C2664: 'GetModuleHandleW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [15]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   6   error C2664: 'CreateEventW' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'const char [20]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   9   error C2664: 'CCmdHandler::AddMessageBytes' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'char *'
Error   7   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [16]' to 'LPTSTR'
Error   8   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [16]' to 'LPTSTR'
Error   1   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'WCHAR [256]' to 'std::string'
```

C++ project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9.00"
    Name="TheProject"
    ProjectGUID="{96791392-AA33-4460-BFEA-D766216ECAA8}"
    RootNamespace="TheProject"
    Keyword="Win32Proj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
    <Platforms>
        <Platform
            Name="Win32"
        />
    </Platforms>
    <ToolFiles>
    </ToolFiles>
    <Configurations>
        <Configuration
            Name="Debug|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="2"
            CharacterSet="1"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="0"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;THEPROJECT_EXPORTS;LOGTOCONSOLE"
                MinimalRebuild="true"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="3"
                RuntimeLibrary="3"
                UsePrecompiledHeader="2"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="4"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
                LinkIncremental="2"
                GenerateDebugInformation="true"
                SubSystem="2"
                TargetMachine="1"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManifestTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCAppVerifierTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
        <Configuration
            Name="Release|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="2"
            CharacterSet="2"
            WholeProgramOptimization="1"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                AdditionalOptions="-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
                Optimization="0"
                InlineFunctionExpansion="1"
                EnableIntrinsicFunctions="true"
                FavorSizeOrSpeed="1"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include&quot;"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;THEPROJECT_EXPORT;LOGTOCONSOLE"
                ExceptionHandling="2"
                RuntimeLibrary="2"
                BufferSecurityCheck="false"
                EnableFunctionLevelLinking="false"
                UsePrecompiledHeader="2"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="3"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
                LinkIncremental="1"
                AdditionalLibraryDirectories="..\lib"
                GenerateDebugInformation="false"
                SubSystem="2"
                OptimizeReferences="2"
                EnableCOMDATFolding="2"
                TargetMachine="1"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManifestTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCAppVerifierTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
    </Configurations>
    <References>
    </References>
    <Files>
        <Filter
            Name="Quelldateien"
            Filter="cpp;c;cc;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx"
            UniqueIdentifier="{4FC737F1-C7A5-4376-A066-2A32D752A2FF}"
            >
            <File
                RelativePath=".\CmdHandler.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\ConsoleCMD.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\dllmain.cpp"
                >
                <FileConfiguration
                    Name="Debug|Win32"
                    >
                    <Tool
                        Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                        UsePrecompiledHeader="0"
                        CompileAsManaged="0"
                    />
                </FileConfiguration>
                <FileConfiguration
                    Name="Release|Win32"
                    >
                    <Tool
                        Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                        UsePrecompiledHeader="0"
                        CompileAsManaged="0"
                    />
                </FileConfiguration>
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\EntiyManager.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\ICommand.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\MiscManager.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\PipeProtocol.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\Pipes.cpp"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\stdafx.cpp"
                >
                <FileConfiguration
                    Name="Debug|Win32"
                    >
                    <Tool
                        Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                        UsePrecompiledHeader="1"
                    />
                </FileConfiguration>
                <FileConfiguration
                    Name="Release|Win32"
                    >
                    <Tool
                        Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                        UsePrecompiledHeader="1"
                    />
                </FileConfiguration>
            </File>
        </Filter>
        <Filter
            Name="Headerdateien"
            Filter="h;hpp;hxx;hm;inl;inc;xsd"
            UniqueIdentifier="{93995380-89BD-4b04-88EB-625FBE52EBFB}"
            >
            <File
                RelativePath=".\CmdHandler.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\CommandIDList.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\ConsoleCMD.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\detours.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\EntiyManager.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\hide.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\ICommand.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\IOnFrameClient.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\Log.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\MiscManager.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\PipeProtocol.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\Pipes.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\stdafx.h"
                >
            </File>
            <File
                RelativePath=".\targetver.h"
                >
            </File>
        </Filter>
        <Filter
            Name="Ressourcendateien"
            Filter="rc;ico;cur;bmp;dlg;rc2;rct;bin;rgs;gif;jpg;jpeg;jpe;resx;tiff;tif;png;wav"
            UniqueIdentifier="{67DA6AB6-F800-4c08-8B7A-83BB121AAD01}"
            >
        </Filter>
        <File
            RelativePath=".\ReadMe.txt"
            >
        </File>
    </Files>
    <Globals>
    </Globals>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

Comment: You have to use the `TCHAR` type and the `TEXT()` macro and all the `_t*` string functions judiciously throughout your code if you want it to compile under either character setting.

Comment: You get these errors because you changed the setting.  Don't change the setting.  You'll have to debug your program to find the real reason it doesn't work properly, a compiler setting is going to magically fix it.

Comment: @Hans Passant there was no change in the project other then loading it in vs2010 from a vs2008 file otherwise it would not compile in the 2008 either.

Comment: @Kerrek what amuses me is the fact it works in 2008.

Comment: You documented compiler errors that were clearly triggered by the setting change.  If you have compiler errors when you change the setting back then you forgot to document them.  Clearly we can't help you sort them out if we don't know what they look like and can't see the code.  I hope that's obvious.

Comment: @Hans I am not arguing that I have a problem what I am saying is that I have done no changes to project other then just opening it from vs2010, I have both versions available and when using 2008 I have 0 errors at all that is what I am questioning.

Comment: @Guapo: You can't just open VS2008 in VS2010 without *converting* it. During the conversion some project setting can be changed. Moreover a general VS2008 project can so many variation, that without having some more information about what you have we can only blind guess.

Comment: @oleg ofc I did the process of converting it as there is no way to open the project without doing so in first place afaik. Would posting the project content help to grab those information ?

Comment: @Guapo: It can be interesting in the case, but in the most cases the conversion protocol has not so helpful. In any way you should provide more information about the application. Currently it's a large black box which just not work and I don't really understand from what you posted what the black box should do.

Comment: @Oleg I understand that but I am sure it might be a configuration related problem in the vs2010 otherwise it would not work in 2008 either.

Comment: Please keep comments professional and on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems not be written to work with UNICODE strings. So you should examine your project settings and verify in the "General" part which "Character Set" you use. I suppose you have "Use Unicode Character Set", but you need to change it to "Not Set". "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" is not the same.

Comment: No Set and Multibyte both let it compile just fine what would be the major difference between the 2 ?

Comment: Probably you have specific setting on the file basis. Do you have many files in the project? You can examine properties of the C++ files. One more problem can be if you use some old libraries compiled with old compiler. Could you examine the "Linker" / "Input" part of your project. If you have the errors during **compilation** of one C/C++ file could you include the code fragment in the question.

Comment: about 10 files not a big project and all links are up to date i will check each file for the properties it have.

Comment: @Guapo: Could you specify more exactly which errors you have in the program if you use "Not Set" setting. You wrote in the question that "no strings work properly can exactly describe what happens to it". It is too unclear for me. Could you debug the code and describe which results of some statement you expected and what you have.

Comment: I am not sure how to debug that but here is what the program does, it hooks an application so we can be able to administrate it from anywhere along the network. When it hooks the given application and we pass information to it which is mainly using a pipe, no strings passed works out as it does when it is compiled in vs2008. If you have any ideas on how I could debug what is happening, I tried to print out every info that is being sent but it does show properly, so I am not sure what happens there. Also thanks for the replies they've been helpfull to me so far ;)

Comment: @Guapo: What kind of "hooking" do the application? More information about the application could be helpful. Is it Win32 or Win64 application? Hooking means typically that the part of your application will be compiled as a DLL. Consist your application from one EXE or has some DLLs. Under debugging I mean just compiling in "Debug" option, setting breakpoints on the suspected of the key (important) places and look what will be done wrong.

Comment: Posted the project option in the main question. Win32, yes it is a DLL, well in the same project a have a console app that does all the debuging but it doesn't catch anything I mean I don't get any errors that will crash or anything alike it just doesn't work to process sent information when using vs2010.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly means `RuntimeLibrary="3"` and `RuntimeLibrary="2"` which you use in your projects. You can try to use "Multi-threaded (/MT)" (or "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)" in the Debug Configuration) at least in the DLL part of the project. In the case the DLL will have not DLL dependency to the C++ runtime and will have the whole C++ runtime function which it uses **inside of  its DLL code**. It reduces the possible of conflicts if you try to inject VS 2010 runtime DLL in another application which uses another version of C++ runtime.